# What are the 13 differences?

Tags: visual

James Fridman a.k.a. @fjamie013 often does humourous manipulations with photos. One of these, from [15 April 2016](https://twitter.com/fjamie013/status/720972156063064065), shows two nearly identical images with — according to James — 13 differences between them.

[image: two images with 13 alleged differences]

I've found some of them, but

**What are these 13 differences?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to describe the differences. Just have a look at this animated gif.

The two images were cropped, upscaled, realigned, then jitter animated.

(Sorry for the late addition - just discovered the thread.)

> [image: 13 differences visually revealed]

Answer (score 6):

[As found by Twitter user tedonkknodet](https://twitter.com/tedonkknodet_/status/722951567830167552) (not me):

> [image: an image highlighting 13 differences]
>
>  List (persons A–E from left to right):
>   1. A's mouth (switched with D's mouth)
>   2. D's mouth (switched with A's mouth)
>   3. B has gotten glasses
>   4. One of C's shirt pockets has disappeared
>   5. Knot of D's tie has been mirrored
>   6. One of A's belt loops has been doubled
>   7. The soles of C's shoes have a different colour
>   8. E's watch or bracelet has disappeared
>   9. There's the reflection of a face in the window next to E
>  10. The black spot on the curb in front of D has disappeared
>  11. There's an extra curtain hanger on the top left
>  12. In the concrete above "ppy" in "Happy", a faint "13" can be seen
>  13. The "snapback", the plastic clip to adjust the size, of E's backwards worn cap, has a different colour
>
>  *I'm still unsure how 1 and 2 should be counted; as a single difference, or as two differences. Using the latter brings the list at the desired 13, unless another difference can be found.*

Comment: Accepting this answer in lieu of an official one by James Fridman.

Answer (score 3):

Partial list:

> * the bug
>  * the glasses on the guy second from the left
>  * the shoe color
>  * the watch
>  * guy on the left's face
>  * top left, there's an extra hole on the top of the wall
>  * middle guy's shirt pocket
>  * color of the thing in the guy on the right's head
>  * there is the reflection of a face in the window in the copy on the right (credit to @SQB)

Comment: "Color of the thing in guy on the right's head" - that's the plastic bit of the hat :P There's also a missing black spot on the sidewalk, towards bottom of screen.

Comment: @n_palum I think that's supposed to be the bug.

Comment: Full disclaimer: I had a head start on this. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39081842#39081842

Comment: Not hiding your answer kind of wrecks it for those of use that want to try and answer.

Comment: @Papa - whoops, sorry. Fixed now. Shows just how long it's been since I wrote an answer here :)

Comment: Id like to add that the face in the window looks like Kanye

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Mithrandir's partial list

> * Mouths switched between the guy on the left and the second guy from the right
>  * Wall is darker at the very top above the y in Happy
>  [image]
>  * Extra belt loop on the guy on the left

Comment: Not seeing a change in the wall's texture

Comment: it's slightly darker in the tan/off-white part in that area, it's hard to see but it's there.  I'm getting a screencap together to add to highlight it

Comment: I could get behind the wall color being darker but it's not a different texture.

Comment: Okay, I've edited it to clear things up

Answer (score 1):

Here they all are.

There are two spots in the concrete that are different, but they may just be from recompression, I couldn't really tell.  Without them it's 13, so they can be ignored.

> [image: Differences]
>
>  List:  (with person on far left as "A")
>   1. Person A mouth
>   2. Person B glasses
>   3. Person C pocket
>   4. Person D mouth
>   5. Person E watch
>   6. Person A belt loop
>   7. Person C left shoe tip
>   8. Person C right shoe tip
>   9. Ghost face image in window
>  10. Black spot on curb
>  11. Extra curtain hanger on top left
>
>  Optionally:
>  12. Concrete above "ppy" in "Happy"
>  13. Concrete in front of Person E's left foot
>
>  Then optionally:
>  14. Time change
>  15. Date change

It's not much of a puzzle when you learn the technique of crossing your eyes so the two photos line up, then look for any of the flickering parts, though I do like the last bit at the end, so to speak.  :)

Comment: The date and time definitely are not part of it

Comment: I see more than 13 circles; would you care to enumerate the differences?

Comment: As far as the date/time, I think that could easily be part of the puzzle.

And as far as enumerating, do they really need to be ordered?  :)

But it's up to you if you count the concrete differences (which I'm not a fan of) and if you count the date differences (which is my favorite part of this "puzzle")

Comment: Added text list

Comment: I'm inclined to count the shoe tips as _one_ difference, not two. Also, the mouths of persons A and D appear to be switched; I'm not sure if that's a single difference or two separates ones, but I'm leaning towards the former.

Answer (score 1):

Another partial

> There's a white spot to the right of his tie, well next to that is a small white  blotch which is missing from the photo on the right[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one... spotted on !

> There is a dark spot at a distance from the feet of participants at the bottom (which is there in the left image but missing in the right one)of the image.

Comment: This has already been mentioned and not really worth another answer vs a comment.